# Do gases have a general upper limit of density?

Tags: pressure, temperature, ideal-gas, states-of-matter

Is there some limit for the density of gases, at which no change in condition could make it more dense without making it fluid, or solid - or something 'in between'?

Comment: There is a temperature/pressure requirement; see [degenerate matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter) for a little bit more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can have a state where increasing the pressure would create a [supercritical fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid)

[image]

See [Phase Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram)

Comment: Looking at the diagram, it feels like the information I want is in there, but I can not get it out :) Could you add some introductory context?